# How to make images appear in a list on mobile screens?

Tags: css, mobile

I have my images in a tables but they show up really squished together or really far apart on mobile screens, is there any coding to get them to be in a vertical line?

```
<body>
<div class="product">
<center><table id="table2">
<tr>
    <td><img src="lipgloss1.png" height="300" width="200"></td>
    <td><img src="lipgloss2.png" height="300" width="200"></td>
    <td><img src="lipgloss3.png" height="300" width="200"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><p>Peridot Green - $3.99</p></td>
    <td><p>Pearl White - $3.99</p></td>
    <td><p>Amethyst Purple - $3.99</p></td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
```

here's the CSS

```
.product {
background-color: white;
margin-left: 3em;
margin-right: 3em;
padding: 2em;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
body img {
    width: 100%;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In such a case i prefer to change the tables behaviour by displaying it as block.

```css
@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
  body img {
    max-width: 100%;
  }
  .product table,
  .product tr,
  .ptoduct td {
    display: block;
  }
  
}
```

So you'll have them in a vertical line. You should also use max-width on images. if you have a 16px facebook icon anywhere in your body width 100% on a 480 device would be terrible.